# Returning a row that matches specified condition, and edit particular columns in row. Then write to csv file with changed row

Tags: python, csv

I'm writing a python script that works with two csv files. Lets call them csv1.csv (original file to read) and csv2.csv (exact copy of csv1). The goal is to find the row and column in the csv file that corresponds to the the modified user-defined input.

csv format:(continues for about 2-3 thousand lines)

```
record LNLIM, ID_CO,OD_DV,ID_LN, ST_LN, ZST_LN, ID_LNLIM,LIMIT1_LNLIM, LIMIT2_LNLIM, LIMIT3_LNLIM
LNLIM, 'FPL', 'SOUT', '137TH_LEVEE_B', 'B', '137TH_AV', 'LEVEE', 'A', 1000, 1100, 1200
LNLIM, 'FPL', 'SOUT', '137TH_DAVIS_B', 'A', '137TH_AV', 'NEWTON', 'A', 1000, 1100, 1200
...
```

Let's say that the user is looking for 137TH_AV and NEWTON. I want to be able to go row by row and compare the two columns/row indices ST_LN and ZST_LN. If both columns match what the user inputted then I want to capture which row in the csv file that happened on, and use that information to edit the remaining columns LIMIT1_LNLIM LIMIT2_LNLIM LIMIT3_LNLIM on that row with new analog values.

I want to get the 3 new values provided by the user and edit a specific row, and a specific row element. Once I've found the place to replace the number values I want to overwrite csv2.csv with this edit.

## Determining where the line segment is located in the array

```
import sys
import csv
import os
import shutil

LineSectionNames = []
ScadaNames = []
with open('Vulcan_Imp_Summary.csv', 'r') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    for row in reader:
        LineSectionName = row[1]
        ScadaName = row[29]
        LineSectionNames.append(LineSectionName)
        ScadaNames.append(ScadaName)

#Reformatting arrays for accurate references        
LineSectionNames = [character.replace('\xa0', ' ') for character in LineSectionNames]
LineSectionNames = [character.replace('?', '-') for character in LineSectionNames]
ScadaNames = [character.replace('\xa0', ' ') for character in ScadaNames]

#Setting Line Section name as key and Scada name as value
ScadaDict = {}
for i in range(len(LineSectionNames)):
    ScadaDict[LineSectionNames[i]] = ScadaNames[i]

#Prompt user for grammatical name of Line Section
print ('Enter the Line Section Name: (Example = Goulds-Princeton) \n')
user_input = input()

#Reference user input to dictionary value to convert input into SCADA format
def reformat():
    print ('Searching for Line Section...' + user_input)
    if user_input in ScadaDict:
        value = ScadaDict[user_input]
        print ('\n\t Match!\n')
    else:
       print ('The Line Section name you have entered was incorrect. Try again. \n Example = Goulds-Princeton')

reformat()

# Copying the exported file from Genesys
path = 'I://PSCO//DBGROUP//PatrickL//'
shutil.copyfile(path + 'lnlim_import.csv', path + 'lnlim_import_c.csv') 

#Using the SCADA format to search through csv file

print ('Searching csv file for...' + user_input)
# Reading the copied file
record_lnlims = []
id_cos = []
id_dvs = []
id_lines = []
id_lns = []
st_lns = []
zst_lns = []
id_lnlims = []
limit1_lnlims = []
limit2_lnlims = []
limit3_lnlims = []

with open('lnlim_import_c.csv', 'r') as copy: 
    reader = csv.reader(copy)
    for row in reader:
        record_lnlim = row[0]
        id_co = row[1]
        id_dv = row[2]
        id_line = row[3]
        id_ln = row[4]
        st_ln = row[5]
        zst_ln = row[6]
        id_lnlim = row[7]
        limit1_lnlim = row[8]
        limit2_lnlim = row[9]
        limit3_lnlim = row[10]
        record_lnlims.append(record_lnlim)
        id_cos.append(id_co)
        id_dvs.append(id_dv)
        id_lines.append(id_line)
        id_lns.append(id_ln)
        st_lns.append(st_ln)
        zst_lns.append(zst_ln)
        id_lnlims.append(id_lnlim)
        limit1_lnlims.append(limit1_lnlim)
        limit2_lnlims.append(limit2_lnlim)
        limit3_lnlims.append(limit3_lnlim)


#Reformatting the user input from GOULDS-PRINCETON to 'GOULDS' and 'PRINCETON'        
input_split = user_input.split('-', 1)
st_ln1 = input_split[0] 
zst_ln1 = input_split[1]
st_ln2 = st_ln1.upper()
zst_ln2 = zst_ln1.upper()
st_ln3 = "'" + str(st_ln2) + "'"
zst_ln3 = "'" + str(zst_ln2) + "'"

#Receiving analog values from user
print ('\n\t Found! \n')
print ('Enter the Specified Emergency Rating (A) for 110% for 7 minutes: ')
limit1_input = input()
print ('Enter the Specified Emergency Rating (A) for 120% for 7 minutes: ')
limit2_input = input()
print ('Enter the Specified Emergency Rating (A) for 130% for 5 minutes: ')
limit3_input = input()
```

Whenever I print the row_index it prints the initialized value of 0.

```
i = 0
row_index = 0

for i in range(len(st_lns)):
    if st_ln3 == st_lns[i] and zst_ln3 == zst_lns[i]:
        row_index = i

print(row_index)
limit1_input = limit1_lnlims[row_index]
limit2_input = limit2_lnlims[row_index]
limit3_input = limit3_lnlims[row_index]

csv_list = []
csv_list.append(record_lnlims)
csv_list.append(id_cos)
csv_list.append(id_dvs)
csv_list.append(id_lines)
csv_list.append(st_lns)
csv_list.append(zst_lns)
csv_list.append(id_lnlims)
csv_list.append(limit1_lnlims)
csv_list.append(limit2_lnlims)
csv_list.append(limit3_lnlims)

#Editing the csv file copy to implement new analog values
with open('lnlim_import_c.csv', 'w') as edit:
    for x in zip(csv_list):
        edit.write("{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}\t{4}\t{5}\t{6}\t{7}\t{8}\t{9}\t{10}\n".format(x))
```

Comment: if `print(row_index)` is printing 0, then your `if st_ln3 == st_lns[i] and zst_ln3 == zst_lns[i]:` must be failing to find a match.  Are you sure this is what you meant?

Comment: How are you reading the first csv? Seems like that is the key

Comment: I'll go ahead post the whole script for reference.